# Is there a way to use aggregators on subselects in Laravel 6.0?

Tags: laravel, eloquent

for example:

```
return Order::addSelect(['total_amount' => Product::select('price')
    ->whereColumn('order_id', 'orders.id')
    ->sum('price');
])->get();
```

I have not been able to get it to work.  The orders.id columns is not available in the query when you use aggregators it seems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using `selectRaw()` in your subquery:

```php
return Order::addSelect(['total_amount' => Product::selectRaw('sum(price)')
    ->whereColumn('order_id', 'orders.id');
])->get();
```